# Hamburger Menu via walker php does not apper

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, wp-nav-walker

I started to develop my first Wordpress theme. I have some issues with the responsive design. While working on my localhost I had no problem with the main navigation. Now we are online and when testing the page on my mobile phone - it does not show the hamburger menu. I followed this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTRZYnYQlmo

Website I am talking about is this one: http://www.vivis.de/

I wonder if the problem is that Gutenberg editor apparently is not working with bootstrap for building up responsive content? So the problem is there and not with the walker.php itself? I`m highly confused.